# Android ContentProvider initialization not at application start

Tags: android, dynamic, android-contentprovider, multiple-databases

is it possible to initialize the contentprovider in the application?

because i need to create a database for every user/server combination and I'm creating the database with the login information in the oncreate method of the the contentprovider!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what it sounds like you are trying to do, you may consider contextualizing your ContentProvider's database access (this may be another way of describing what @Gary B. was getting at):

When you initialize the content provider, create a database within which you will store the list of user/server combinations.  Then, when a user logs into the application, create the corresponding database and update the master list for the ContentProvider.

In the ContentProvider's public operations, determine which user/server combination is active (or being requested) and then look up the appropriate database in the master database you created on installation.  You can then read the user/server specific information and return this to the caller.

Alternatively, you could likely implement this all within one database, but I don't understand enough about your requirements to recommend a specific approach...

Answer (score 0):

An [SQLiteOpenHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html) is usually the place to do database creation. More specifically the [`onCreate(SQLiteDatabase)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onCreate%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase%29) method. It will create the database when the app is installed.

Comment: I would probably create an empty database in the method I mentioned and then insert the user information in that existing database during login.

Comment: I will try to explain it better: I have a database for every user/server combination like admin_10.1.0.1.db which will be created after login. the data in the database has no relevance for the login, because the server checks the login information!